# Cannot import Ethereum web3.js in React Native application

Tags: web3js, import

I'm trying to import the Ethereum [web3.js library](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API) into a React Native project.

I've followed the React [Linking Libraries](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/linking-libraries-ios.html) instructions, installing the web3.js package and linking it with the commands:

```
$ npm install web3 --save
$ react-native link
```

My `index.ios.js` file looks as follows:

```
import { default as Web3 } from 'web3';

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { AppRegistry, Text } from 'react-native';

class ReactProject extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Text>Hello world!</Text>
    );
  }
}

AppRegistry.registerComponent('ReactProject', () => ReactProject);
```

The error message I receive in the simulator when I run the app  `{"type":"InternalError","message":"react-packager has encountered an internal error, please check your terminal error output for more details"}` is not very helpful as the terminal shows only the same message.

How do I go about importing this library, into other projects such as React-Native?

Comment: I think the actual error message is missing here. As it says you need to dig deeper from terminal, logs, wherever where the actual error message is printed out.

Comment: After restarting the simulator and packager I have a new error about a missing module, which I've resolved by editing the require statement in `https://github.com/debris/bignumber.js/blob/master/bignumber.js`. I've posted an issue with fix details here: https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/issues/576. Does anybody know why `web3` uses the `debris/bignumber.js` fork of the `MikeMcl/bignumber.js` module?

Answer (score 1):

**Fixed:**  https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/issues/576

Edit The Following File

```
/node_modules/bignumber.js/bignumber.js
```

edit as follows:

```
-if ( !crypto ) try { crypto = require('crypto'); } catch (e) {}
+if ( !crypto ) try { crypto = require('crypto-js'); } catch (e) {}
```

**Web3 Version: 0.18.2**

Import in respective file

```
var Web3 = require('web3'); or import { default as Web3 } from 'web3';
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to make it work on web3 version 0.x with `web3 version 0.20.0`, `react 16 fiber`

For more info see the following [sample app](https://gitlab.com/dapps/react-native-web3-sample).

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/markspereira/react-native-web3-boilerplate I managed to get web3 1.0.0 working. For account creation I use 'ethereumjs-wallet' as it doesn't work with the web3 1.0.0 on react-native and that pretty much covers everything you would want to do.